# Saving sensitive data in database - secure server communication

Tags: android, security, google-app-engine, google-play, google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple game where you can choose to buy premium. If you do, I change your version-value from 0 to 1 in the User-table of my Google Datastore.

I have a lot of other calls as well, but this is the only one that really matters if it gets compromised.

I've been told that the only way to do this securely is to do it on server-side, but I must somehow tell my server that the user just bought premium, which means I need an endpoint for it in my API, which means it's not done fully on the server, so what do they mean when they say this?

I secure my communication like follows:

1. send username/pass to server
2. salt pass, hash it, store it in db
3. create an access token, store it in db with userId, return token to client
4. save token in preferences, all calls to API must have token attached

This also means that a user can just grab the token from preferences, and call my API-endpoint however they want. Maybe I am missing some part of the oauth process since I made this my self, but what step am I missing? It just feels very vulnerable to reverse engineering.

What can I do to make sure that nobody else can call my API? And if that isn't possible, what can I add to my flow to make it more secure?

Comment: On top of all of above things, you can also apply encryption to your database. Here is the link:

https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal and future-proof way is to have a Backend service that checks whether the user is subscribed or not every time when the user signs-in.

Relying on the local storage is not recommended as the user might switch phones.(Even from Android to iOS).

Once the user finishes a purchase, you should send a request to the API, and the back-end should check with Google merchant DB(or iOS merchant) whether he has actually purchased it. 
If so, an entry has to be made in the Backend-DB with receipt ID,OS type(iOS or Android) and expiry date.
You just need two end points in Backend:

1. purchaseDone() - this registers the OS type in Backend DB after checking with Merchant DB.
2. isSubscriptionActive() - true/false response.
   This should check the Google/iOS merchant. You should call this every-time when user signs in.(Also delete record in local DB if purchase expired).

Some helpful links for your Backend service:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products

Comment: Of course I check if the user is subbed or not every time he signs in, along with all other info I need. This does not help with my concern that if a "hacker" gets hold of the accestoken, he can take it, and call my API using it. My database is in the cloud, so no local storage, only preferences (I have to save access token locally somewhere, or user has to sign in every time they start my app)

Comment: Do u have an expiry time for access_token?(You should) Make sure its validity time is not more than 5 minutes( Backend services like amazon usually have not more than 5 minutes). Once your access_token expires, you should revoke it with id and password(Basic auth).  Even if hacker gets your access token, the API business logic should check whether he has done an actual purchase in Google merchant server before making an entry in your backend DB. Its more unlikely for a hacker to get acess to it within its expiry time. To make it even more secure, obfuscate with SALT and Proguard your app.

Comment: Cool, Ill look into how to check if a user has made a purchase or not